# Como imprimir uma matriz com índices e valores em PHP?

Tags: php, matriz

Tenho a seguinte matriz em PHP:

```
$matriz['HGF']['Christus'] = 7;
$matriz['HGF']['Unifor'] = 6;
$matriz['HIAS']['Christus'] = 5;
$matriz['HIAS']['Unifor'] = 4;
```

Gostaria de imprimir a matriz em html, exibindo índices e valores, assim:

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td> </td>
           <td> Christus </td>
           <td> Unifor </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td> HGF </td>
           <td align="center"> 7 </td>
           <td align="center"> 6 </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td> HIAS </td>
           <td align="center"> 5 </td>
           <td align="center"> 4 </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Consegui fazer isso num array unidimensional utilizando o foreach, mas não estou conseguindo nessa matriz.

Comment: Mas você quer que a tabela inteira seja dinamica , feita pelo PHP ou apenas onde está o resultado ?

Comment: A tabela é dinâmica, formada por dados retirados do banco (inclusive os índices são dinâmicos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O primeiro `foreach` vai percorrer a matriz e pegar os indices para criar o topo da tabela e ele tem um `break` para que rode apenas uma vez, dependendo de como é gerada essa matriz pode ficar desorganizado porem se todos tiverem os mesmos indeces na mesma ordem vai ficar tudo ok, o segundo `foreach` vai pegar os valores e preencher a tabela
O codigo seria o seguinte :

```
<?php 
    $matriz = array(
            "HGF" => array(
                    "Christus" =>7,
                    "Unifor" =>6,
            ),
            "HIAS"=>array(
                    "Christus" =>5,
                    "Unifor" =>4,
            )
    );
?>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <?php 
                    foreach ($matriz as $key => $value) {
                        foreach ($value as $title => $result) {
                            $head .= "<td> " . $title . " </td>";
                        }
                        echo $head;
                        break;
                    }
                    foreach ($matriz as $key => $value) {
                        $body = "<tr>";
                        $body .= "<td> " . $key . " </td>";
                        foreach ($value as $title => $result) {
                            $head .= "<td> " . $title . " </td>";
                            $body .= "<td align='center'>" . $result . "</td>";
                        }
                        $body .= "</tr>";
                        echo $body;
                    }
                ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Preciso que os td's sejam dinâmicos também. Os índices Christus e Unifor são apenas exemplos. Eles podem mudar de acordo com o que estiver no banco.

Comment: @CamilaColares e como q é gerada essa matriz , pq a resposta pode depender de como ela vem mas , eu dei uma editada para uma possivel solução, se isso lhe servir ou ficar uma duvida so dar um toque

Comment: Perfeito, @ViniciusShiguemori!! Muito obrigada!!!

Answer (score 2):

Seria assim, onde você digitou os valores, você vai imprimir a matriz:

```
 <td><?php echo $matriz['HGF']['Cristus'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $matriz['HGF']['Unifor'] ?></td>

 <td><?php echo $matriz['HIAS']['Cristus'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $matriz['HIAS']['Unifor'] ?></td>
```

Primeiramente, certifique-se que esta passando a matriz correta para a página