# Ler Array Multidimensional PHP

Tags: php

Preciso ler um array e pegar o nome de sua coluna e seu valor.

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Conta] => FRANCIELE OLIVEIRA
            [CPF] => ''
            [Telefone Res.] => (00) 0000-0000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Conta] => BEATRIX BEHN
            [CPF] => ''
            [Telefone Res.] => (00) 0000-0000
        )
)


foreach ($Array as $row)
{
    echo $row['Conta'];
    echo $row['CPF'].'<BR><BR>';
}
```

Mas, com este foreach só me é impresso os valores, preciso também do nome da coluna, por exemplo: `Conta = BEATRIX`

Answer (score 5):

Tem que utilizar um `foreach` que pode resgatar inclusive o indice, ***exemplo***:

```
foreach ($array as $r => $k)
{        
}
```

onde o `$r` é o índice e o `$k` é o valor *respectivo*, só que no seu exemplo tem que criar dois `foreach`, porque é um `array` que contem `array` e para buscar o índices do `array` mais interno, utilize a técnica acima, exemplo:

```
<?php

$Array = array(
    array("Conta"=>"FRANCIELE OLIVEIRA", "CPF"=>"","Telefone Res."=>'(00) 0000-0000'),
    array("Conta"=>"BEATRIX BEHN", "CPF" => "","Telefone Res."=>'(00) 0000-0000')
);

foreach ($Array as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $i => $a)
    {
        echo '<div>'. $i." ".$a .'</div>';
    }
}
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/GoVegN)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Pegar o indice do array em um foreach](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/307200-pegar-o-indice-do-array-em-um-foreach/)
- [How to find the foreach index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141108/how-to-find-the-foreach-index)
- [How can I get the current array index in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450157/how-can-i-get-the-current-array-index-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 2):

No foreach use a sintaxe `$key => $value` isso vai devolver os repectivos nome da chave e o valor.

mude:

```
foreach ($Array as $row)
```

Para:

```
 foreach ($Array as $chave => $row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Você só precisa dar uma modificada no seu `for`

```
foreach ($Array as $key => $row)
{
    // seu codigo
}
```

onde a variavel `$key` tem o valor do id do array, ja respondi uma pergunta parecida aqui o link : [Como imprimir uma matriz com índices e valores em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249848/)